# How to iterate prefixes or suffixes of vec or slice in rust?

Tags: rust, iterator, slice, prefix, suffix

I have a vec: `vec![1, 2, 3, 4]`. I want to know how to:

- Iterate its prefixes from shortest to longest:

  &[], &[1], &[1, 2], &[1, 2, 3], &[1, 2, 3, 4]
- Iterate its prefixes from longest to shortest:

  &[1, 2, 3, 4], &[1, 2, 3], &[1, 2], &[1], &[]
- Iterate its suffixes from shortest to longest:

  &[], &[4], &[3, 4], &[2, 3, 4], &[1, 2, 3, 4]
- Iterate its suffixes from longest to shortest:

  &[1, 2, 3, 4], &[2, 3, 4], &[3, 4], &[4], &[],

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See also: [How to iterate prefixes and suffixes of str or String in rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68845686/14516046)

- What works for a `&[T]` (i.e. a slice) will also work for `&Vec<T>` due to [Deref coercion](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch15-02-deref.html#implicit-deref-coercions-with-functions-and-methods)
- To construct a range of indexes from 0 to slice.len() inclusive: `0..=slice.len()`
- std::ops::Range implements both [Iterator](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/struct.Range.html#impl-Iterator) and [DoubleEndedIterator](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/struct.Range.html#impl-DoubleEndedIterator). This allows you to use the rev() method:

  (0..=slice.len()).rev()
- To get a prefix of a given length: `&slice[..len]`
- To get a suffix without the first `cut` items: `&slice[cut..]`

## Putting it all together

To iterate from shortest to longest:

```
pub fn prefixes_asc<T>(slice: &[T]) -> impl Iterator<Item = &[T]> + DoubleEndedIterator {
    (0..=slice.len()).map(move |len| &slice[..len])
}

pub fn suffixes_asc<T>(slice: &[T]) -> impl Iterator<Item = &[T]> + DoubleEndedIterator {
    (0..=slice.len()).rev().map(move |cut| &slice[cut..])
}
```

To reverse just use .rev():

```
pub fn prefixes_desc<T>(slice: &[T]) -> impl Iterator<Item = &[T]> + DoubleEndedIterator {
    prefixes_asc(slice).rev()
}

pub fn suffixes_desc<T>(slice: &[T]) -> impl Iterator<Item = &[T]> + DoubleEndedIterator {
    suffixes_asc(slice).rev()
}
```

[tests](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=c4801060d462daef29984f6aa6ccea1b)

Comment: You could also return `impl Iterator<Item = &[T]> + DoubleEndedIterator` from the two "ascending" functions and call `.rev()` on the result in their respective "descending" counterparts to avoid duplication (at this point, having the "desc" versions doesn't make a lot of sense anymore, since callers can also call `.rev`)